# Is an advanced (multiple) join possible with dplyr?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, erd

is it possible to do a join as the example ERD with dplyr?

see advanced join ERD example:

[image: ERD example]

Comment: Just looks like 4 left joins to me.

Comment: Why to call it advance?

Comment: First change the name of the last dataframe that you have from city name to city, then out all the dataframes in a list. Now use reduce, with function being leftjoin